# What is "..." directory (three dot)?

Tags: windows, directory

I am writing a program using ASP.NET 6. In my program I use [Directory.CreateDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-6.0) to create required directories.

Due to some mistake, I let it create a folder named `...` (three dot) like this:

```cs
Directory.CreateDirectory(".../MyFolder");
```

I discovered that this `...` folder points to its parent. For example, in the case `D:\Parent1\Parent2\...`, opening the `...` folder directs me to `Parent2` (which is also the same folder I am in).

This folder cannot be deleted using Windows Explorer, `del` (cmd) or `rm` (PowerShell). It can be moved to another folder.
I also discovered that I cannot create a folder named "..." using Windows Explorer.

**My question is:** What is this `...` directory? Is it some kind of special directory like `.` and `..`, and if so why is it not documented anywhere?
(I did some Google search and only found people talking about `.` and `..`).

---

More context about my mistake: In my program, the direct to be created is parameterized.

The actual code looks like this:

```cs
string prefix = "..";                 // It should be "../", I forgot the slash
string folderName = "./MyFolder";     // The "./" part is to prevent case like "ParentFolderMyFolder" when I forgot the slash

Directory.CreateDirectory(prefix + folderName);
```

I expected it to be `.././MyFolder`, which is creating a folder named "MyFolder" in the previous directory, but I forgot one slash and it became `.../MyFolder`.